# Benefits of using pglogical 2.4.1 over Postgres 12 build-in logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-12, pg-logical

I'm migrating a Postgres version 12.14 database. I've tested the migration twice: once using the pglogical extension 2.4.1 and once using Postgres' built-in logical replication. It seems like pglogical is just a wrapper for the build-in statements. For example, the creation of a pglogical replication set seems to be analogous to creating a publication.

What are the benefits of using one over the other?

These are the benefits I've found of using pglogical:

- there's a way of updating sequences on the target using `pglogical.replication_set_add_all_sequences`.
- there's a way to handle tables without a keys using the replication set `default_insert_only`.